# Netlogo creating a turtle with one variable set by a procedure

Tags: netlogo

i have this code to crate a turtle of a certain brees (nodi)

```
  create-nodi 1 [  
  set hidden? true
  set x 0 
  set y 0 
  set larg lato 
  set altez lato
  set livello n 
  set media mean [valore] of patches with [ nel-quadrato? x  Y  larg ]
  ]
```

i need to set the variable media as the mean of the variable valore (a patch variable) of the patches that respond positively to the returner nel-quadrato?( a  boolean returner ).

this returner should have 3 argumentes (x, y, larg) of the turtle i'm trying to create.

I cannot find a way to express tha the 3 arguments belog to the turtle that i'm creating and not to the patches; in fact i have this error:

```
you cant use x in patch contex because is turtle only
```

Comment: can you please post the code for the `nel-quadrato?` procedure? One approach may be to make this a four argument procedure and have the turtle as one of the arguments. If so, you could pass `self`.

Comment: for now is a returner that return always true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `myself` here to refer to the asking turtle:

```
patches with [nel-quadrato? [x] of myself
                            [y] of myself
                            [larg] of myself]
```

If this seems clunky, another way to do the same thing would be to use `let`:

```
let my-x x
let my-y y
let my-larg larg
patches with [nel-quadrato? my-x my-y my-larg]
```

I also like JenB's suggestion to consider refactoring.